# How to display simple HTML formatted text in Winforms, including hyperlinks, without web engines?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, hyperlink, controls

I want to display simple HTML formatted text in my WinForms application. The only functionality I need, is just to display it correctly, and have the ability to click on a hyperlink that will open the system's web browser.

I don't need full webpage functionality, with navigation and JavaScript. It will be a notification's system for the user, so I only want to display popup with a message. I want to use it as an alternative to RichTextBox, because RichTextBox has a lot of events,properties to set to make it behave like I want. I want an HTML formatted text presenter only.

Is there a control or other way to achieve this, without using full WebBroswer engines or controls?

Answer (score 3):

Please, check out the following solutions:

The first one is a C# lib:
https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer

> This library is 100% managed C# code without any external dependencies
>   (no WebBrowser control, ActiveX / COM or MSHTML dll), the only
>   requirement is .NET 2.0 or higher.

The second one is a Winforms HTML editor project that may be useful for you:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a

> The purpose of the Html Editor is to provide Html Editing capabilities
>   within a WinForms control. The control should emulate the operations
>   that are available within a Rich Text control, but have information
>   persisted and restored from an Html BODY element.

Comment: Html Renderer seems promising